# SignalR not Loading in Angular

Tags: angular

I'am using signalR Client in my angular .net Core app,
I cant load my app when am using signalR, other wise my app works fine. I think the issue lies with my systemjs.config but I am not able to figure out the issue.
Am using npm i @aspnet/signalr

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      'npm:': 'lib/'
    },
    map: {
      app: 'app',
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
      'three': 'npm:three.js',
      'trackball': 'npm:TrackballControls.js',
      '@aspnet/signalr': 'npm:@aspnet/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js'
    },
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Last line in map{} is where I have included signalR

Following is my sample service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HubConnectionBuilder } from '@aspnet/signalr';

@Injectable()

export class signalRService {

  ngOnInit() { 
      let hubconnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl('/abc').build;
  } 
}
```

if I comment let hubconnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl('/abc').build; my app works fine, 
There is no console errors also.